# How to sort objects in a JSON array by an object property?

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-order-by, plpgsql, jsonb

I have this PL/pgSQL function to aggregate rows from two tables in a `jsonb` value (`data_table_1` and `data_table_2`). `fk_id` is a common foreign key id in both tables:

```sql
DECLARE
v_my_variable_1 jsonb;
v_my_variable_2 jsonb;
v_combined      jsonb;
BEGIN
  SELECT json_agg( data_table_1 ) INTO v_my_variable FROM data_table_1 WHERE fk_id = v_id;
  SELECT json_agg( data_table_2 ) INTO v_my_variable_2 FROM data_table_2 WHERE fk_id = v_id;
  SELECT v_my_variable || v_my_variable_2 INTO v_combined;
```

Now I want to sort `v_combined` by the field "ts", a timestamp column common to both tables, and consequently a common key in all array objects in the `jsonb` value.

Example:

```
v_combined = '[{"id": 1, "type": 4, "param": 3, "ts": 12354355}
             , {"id": 1, "txt": "something", "args": 5, "ts": 12354345}]';
```

How do I sort array elements in `v_combined` in ascending order for `ts`?

If I were selecting from a table I could simply use:

```
select * into v_combined from v_combined ORDER BY v_combined->>'ts' ASC;
```

But when I try that, it says that `v_combined` does not exist. Is there a way of storing it in a temp table and sorting there, or is there a direct way to sort the array of JSON objects in PL/pgSQL?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Your code is not self-explanatory.

Comment: Now edited to clarify the end result that I want. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I'm still not quite there; sorry for being obtuse. a) `jsonb` doesn't have a concept of ordering for elements. b) `SELECT v_combined || v_my_variable into v_my_variable_2;` overwrites `v_my_variable_2` that you just wrote. All in all, I have the suspicion that all this should not happen with `jsonb` values, but with table rows. You can use `jsonb_populate_recordset` to convert `jsonb` to a table. Or you can store the data in table format.

Comment: You have `SELECT v_combined || v_my_variable into v_my_variable_2;`. I assume you meant to write `SELECT v_my_variable || v_my_variable_2 into v_combined;`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I am a fan of your high-quality posts, but I suspect a misunderstanding this time: `jsonb` *does* have a concept of ordering for array elements.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the concatenation statement to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right - I mixed up "order of elements in" and "order of *array* elements".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The ***order of keys in an object*** in a `jsonb` literal is insignificant - object keys are sorted internally anyway. (`json` is different in this regard.) See:

- [Customize jsonb key sort order involving arrays](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/142108/3684)

The ***order of array elements*** in a `jsonb` (or `json`) literal is significant, though. Your request is meaningful. You can reorder like this:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(elem)
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(v_combined) a(elem)
   ORDER  BY (elem->>'ts')::int  -- order by integer value of "ts"
   ) sub;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2ca5fd8dd6ddaf444b0fc79fe529f64a)*

But it would be **more efficient** to order the array *before* assigning it:

```
...
DECLARE
   v_combined      jsonb;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO v_combined  jsonb_agg(elem)
   FROM  (
      SELECT ts, json_agg(data_table_1) AS j
      FROM   data_table_1
      WHERE  fk_id = v_id

      UNION ALL 
      SELECT ts, json_agg(data_table_2)
      FROM   data_table_2
      WHERE  fk_id = v_id
      ORDER  BY ts
      ) sub;
...
```

#### On the order of rows from a subquery

In standard SQL the ***order of rows*** in a subquery (or any table expression) is insignificant as well. But in Postgres the order of rows in subqueries is carried over to the next level. So this works in simple queries. It's even [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

> ... supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT xmlagg(x) FROM (SELECT x FROM test ORDER BY y DESC) AS tab;
> ```
>
> Beware that this approach can fail if the outer query level contains additional processing, such as a join, because that might cause the subquery's output to be reordered before the aggregate is computed.

If you can't or won't rely on this, there is a safe alternative: add an `ORDER BY` to the aggregate function itself. That's even shorter:

```
SELECT INTO v_combined  jsonb_agg(elem  ORDER BY (elem->>'ts')::int)
FROM   jsonb_array_elements(v_combined) a(elem);
```

But it's typically *slower*.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you very much! I'd double up vote it if I could.