# PostgreSQL 13 - How to order recursive JSON hierarchy

Tags: json, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I need to represent a document structure as a JSON object to be passed to a web application to form a hierarchical tree. Of course the order of the components needs to be correct so I am searching for a way to order the parents and children. So every child should be ordered by child_order asc

How could I do that?

Here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE documents_structure (
     id INTEGER NOT NULL
   , title CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL
   , parent_id INTEGER
   , child_order INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

The Insert queries:

```
INSERT INTO documents_structure (id,title,parent_id,child_order) VALUES (1,'Root of the document', NULL,1);
INSERT INTO documents_structure (id,title,parent_id,child_order) VALUES (2,'First Child of root', 1,1);
INSERT INTO documents_structure (id,title,parent_id,child_order) VALUES (3,'Second Child of root', 1,2);
INSERT INTO documents_structure (id,title,parent_id,child_order) VALUES (4,'Third Child of root', 1,3);
INSERT INTO documents_structure (id,title,parent_id,child_order) VALUES (5,'First Child of Branch 1', 2,1);
INSERT INTO documents_structure (id,title,parent_id,child_order) VALUES (6,'Second Child of Branch 1', 2,2);
```

And the query to retrieve the JSON hierarchy:

```
WITH RECURSIVE document_tree("id", "title", "parent_id", "child_order", "children") AS (
  -- tree leaves (no matching children)
  SELECT c.id,c.title,c.parent_id,c.child_order, json '[]'
  FROM documents_structure c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id,title,parent_id,child_order FROM documents_structure AS hypothetic_child WHERE hypothetic_child.parent_id = c.id)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (parent).id,(parent).title,(parent).parent_id,(parent).child_order, json_agg(child) AS "children"
  FROM (
    SELECT parent, child
    FROM document_tree AS child
    JOIN documents_structure parent ON parent.id = child.parent_id
  ) branch
  GROUP BY branch.parent
)
SELECT jsonb_pretty(json_agg(t)::jsonb)
FROM document_tree t
LEFT JOIN documents_structure AS hypothetic_parent ON(hypothetic_parent.id = t.parent_id)
WHERE hypothetic_parent.id = 1;
```

For your convenience I have made a [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h96ih2QhNFDk2jW7ptVejA/0)

Comment: Nice question: +1 for the thoroughness (it's scarce here these days). Forgive me if I'm oversimplifying your question, but adding a order by wouldn't suffice? see fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bf2613e96f97067b8a8de7fb450de118

Comment: Thanks for your help and the thumbs up. I'm still stuck with the ordering of the array.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206719/how-to-sort-objects-in-an-array-inside-a-json-or-jsonb-value-by-a-property-of-th) seems inspiring but I did not manage to adapt it to sort my array.