# How can I aggregate rows in order?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.*, po.product_options
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN  (
        SELECT po.p_id, 
               json_agg(
                  json_build_object('id', po.id, 'name', po.name, 'options', pom.option_name)) AS product_options
        FROM product_options po
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT product_options_id, json_agg(option_name) as option_name
          FROM product_options_value
          GROUP BY product_options_id
          ) pom ON pom.product_options_id = po.id
        GROUP BY p_id
    ) po ON po.p_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Here is a db fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b47e3b/8

Now I want to order rows from the table `product_options` by the column `s_position`. I get:

> ERROR:  column "po.s_position" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

But if I add the column to `GROUP BY`, I get 2 rows instead of just one. How can I order by `s_position` at the table `product_options` so that I still get the same result, but with ordered options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After aggregating all rows from `product_options` per `p_id` in the subquery, trying to order by `product_options.s_position` would be ambiguous. Hence the error message you saw.

To aggregate rows from `product_options` in the order set by `s_position`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   product p
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT po.p_id AS id
        , json_agg(json_build_object('id', id, 'name', name, 'options', pom.option_name)
                   ORDER BY po.s_position) AS product_options  -- !
   FROM   product_options po
   JOIN  (
      SELECT product_options_id AS id, json_agg(option_name) AS option_name
      FROM   product_options_value
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) pom USING (id)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) po USING (id)
WHERE  p.id = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iqSAAVIV)

Alternatively, you might order rows in an additional subquery, which is typically faster. See:

- [How to sort objects in an array inside a json or jsonb value by a property of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206719/how-to-sort-objects-in-an-array-inside-a-json-or-jsonb-value-by-a-property-of-th/49241241#49241241)

Comment: Thank you very much !